# adb not able to detect Pixel 2 in mac

Tags: android, macos

I was using mac(regular not the touch bar once) and trying to use device Pixel 2 to work with Android studio. I was not able to see pixel 2 detected in adb. Tried using Android File Transfer and some other options such as Developer options reset, MTP or PTP instead of charging.
Need some help on this.

Comment: Related thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/7lj50n/apparently_the_pixel_2_nonxl_doesnt_like_usb_3031/

Comment: Insert the usb type c cable upside down.

Comment: @AnupamChugh Seriously?

Comment: @GlennMohammad yes, it worked for me! Do look this up on the internet for the "why".

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved something similar in my MacBook Pro. My solution might work for you.

Navigate to the location where you have your Android SDK installed and make sure that the adb tool and all the other platform tools are in the folder called platform-tools under the Android sdk folder.

For example, in my case, Android SDK is in `/Users/drstrange/Library/Android/sdk` and my `adb` is in `/Users/drstrange/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`.

But when I was still having `adb` issues, I have discovered that the platform-tools location was `/Users/drstrange/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/platform-tools/`.

All I had to do was moving all the files from `/Users/drstrange/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/platform-tools/` to `/Users/drstrange/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/`

Somehow, this was automatically installed by Android Studio and yet, it did it the wrong way.

After making that change, everything started working instantly without any need to restart or unplug/replug the phone.